# problems downloading signed pdf files c#

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, signed, downloading-website-files

I have a signed pdf with Adobe signature well done. My problem starts when I want to download this document.

Via webmethod I get the bytes of the signed file. Until here there is no problems.

If I try to save the file in my server, when I open the file everything is correct. But if I try to download it when I open it the signature is wrong.

This is the error in adobe reader:

> "The scope of the signed data is defined by a range of unexpected bytes.
>   Details: The range of bytes of the signature is invalid"

This is the way I download the file:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= Factura.pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", newStream.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(newStream.GetBuffer(), 0, newStream.GetBuffer().Length);
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending more bytes than thos advertised in the header. Do `newStream.ToArray()` and only use the byte array. Other thing to check is if you really have all the bytes in `newStream`, save it to a file to check (from the `ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed this line: `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", newStream.Length.ToString());` for this other: `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", newStream.ToArray().Length.ToString());` and I have the same problem. 
I can check that `newStream` have all the bytes. because I save the file before download it and I can read it perfectly